# is it a requirement to initialize firestore inside a project ? or can I just write the rules inside the google console?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

is it a requirements to initialize fire store inside a react app ? or can I just write the rules inside the google console ? I mean what are the use case for the initialization other than writing the rules locally inside vs rather then the webpage?

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
//import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/fireStore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_Key,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you show (preferably in code) what you mean by "initialize firestore inside a react app"? And what "just write the rules inside the google console" means and what is has to bo the initializing the app?

Comment: when I write inside the terminal firestore init. inside the command line and i get those question and stuff

Comment: Assuming you mean `firebase init`, which executes the Firebase command-line interface, then there's no struct need to run that. But you will need to initialize Firebase in your code for it to be able to find your project on the servers. --- It's more likely we can help if you edit your question to show a problem/the code where you are stuck.

Comment: the issue is it all works ok, i just imported the , I added my main firebase folder but the i just don't use cli....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase CLI is a convenient way to initialize your usage of some Firebase products in your project, but it is not required.

You *will* need to import the relevant SDKs and initialize Firebase by calling `initializeApp` in your code for it to be able to find your project on the servers. But it doesn't matter if that imports and call are generated by a tool like the CLI or if you get them from somewhere else.

Comment: thanks frank so if I understated right, my current imports are another way of doing the init ?